# How to force uninstall sequence within install sequence in InstallShield

Tags: installation, installshield, uninstallation, installscript

I want my installer to prompt the user to uninstall an existing installation before installing the new one if an installation already exists at the selected install directory.

Right now I'm trying to just call the uninstall dialog and let it continue its normal execution from there, but since it is already in the install sequence, it continues to run functions for installing, rather than uninstalling.

Is this even possible to do? And if not, how else might I accomplish the same thing.

I'm using a Basic MSI project, and due to the nature of my installation, I don't believe I'll be able to set up a Major upgrade.

Comment: If you need to uninstall an application before installing a new one, it sounds like exact scenario for major upgrade. Why do you think you'll not be able to set it up? If you elaborate on this, it might be easier to answer your question.

Comment: @YanSklyarenko Well, I don't *always* want to uninstall before installing. I only want to uninstall before installing if there is an existing application **at the same location**. And even then, I only want to uninstall the **one** instance of the application that is located where we're trying to install the new one.

Comment: @YanSklyarenko If there were/is a way to have a major upgrade call RemoveExistingProducts on only the one product, I'd be fine. To my knowledge, though, you can only control which *versions* it removes.